# Why does my react native app not update state on ios device?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm trying to show an icon when my app makes a request to the backend. But sometimes the icon does not disappear.
I have the following code:

```
const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  _fetchForm();
}, []);

async function _fetchForm () {
  try {
    setSpinner(true);
    const form = await api.fetchCreateForm();
    dispatch(swotsActions.setSwotsForm(form));
    setSpinner(false);
  } catch {
    setSpinner(false);
  }
}

if (!spinner) {
  return <Form/>;
} else {
  return <Spinner/>;
}
```

The Spinner component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, Modal, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import { colors } from 'utilities/styles';

export default function Spinner () {
  return (
    <Modal
      onRequestClose={() => {}}
      transparent={true}
      visible={true}
    >
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <ActivityIndicator
          animating={true}
          color={colors.black}
          size='large'
        />
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

And only on ios devices sometimes both components appear

I using expo sdk 44, the same code works on skd 42 (which will be deprecated soon)

Comment: You have programmed the component to show a spinner forever if there's an error, or if fetchCreateForm never completes.

Comment: I hadn't seen it. But anyway, the issue keeps happening

Comment: Use a finally block instead `finally {setSpinner(false); }`. However based on your description it seems like this code is not actually the root of your problem. How could both the Form and the Spinner be in the dom?

Comment: ok I will try with the finally block, anyway thank you for your attention